# How to multithread using threading

Tags: python, multithreading

The `queueLock.acquire()` line hangs a code that tries to take advantage of threading and Queue modules with following output:

`run() on <newThread(Thread-1, started 4344102912)>`

`run() on <newThread(Thread-2, started 4348309504)>`

`...working delay: 1`

Why?

```
import threading, thread, Queue, time

class newThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay=0, workQueue=None):
        self.delay=delay
        self.workQueue=workQueue
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print '\nrun() on %s'%self
        print_time(self.delay, self.workQueue)
        print '\nrun() exit %s'%self

def print_time(delay=None, workQueue=None):
    def onExit():
        if not workQueue.empty():
            data = workQueue.get()
            queueLock.release()
        else:
            queueLock.release()

    counter=0
    while True:
        queueLock.acquire()
        time.sleep(delay)
        print '\t...working delay: %s'%delay   

        if counter>5:
            onExit()

        counter=counter + 1



queueLock = threading.Lock()
workQueue = Queue.Queue(10)
threads = []

thread1 = newThread(delay=1, workQueue=workQueue)
thread1.start()
threads.append(thread1)

thread2 = newThread(delay=2, workQueue=workQueue)
thread2.start()
threads.append(thread2)

queueLock.acquire()
print '1. workQueue.empty():',workQueue.empty()
workQueue.put('One')
print '2. workQueue.empty():',workQueue.empty()
workQueue.put('Two')

queueLock.release()

#Wait for queue to empty
while not workQueue.empty():
    print '...passing while not workQueue.empty()'
    pass

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print '...completed'
```

Comment: Error message and stack trace would be very helpful. It would also help to show what the output is (i.e. which of your `print` lines actually executed)

Comment: Are you running standard C-based Python? If so, you can't do multithreading in the traditional sense. Look at the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)

Comment: @Tyler: GIL has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Some suggestions for your code: You don't have to derive from `Thread`, you can simply run any function with a plain `Thread` instance. It would also help if you didn't specify default parameters for functions where they may no sense at all, like passing `None` as queue to `print_time()`. Also, upgrade to Python 3!

Comment: Please post some example on how to run any function with a plain `Thread` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`queueLock.acquire()` blocks until `queueLock.release()` is called if `queueLock` is already acquired. `counter > 5` never happens because even if `queueLock` is available on the first iteration of the loop; nothing releases it on the 2nd iteration.

`Queue()` has its own locks. Drop `queueLock` completely.

Comment: I'd like to add that in order to not forget releasing a lock, you can use it as context manager, i.e. `with some_lock.acquire(): ...`.